# Dropdown in jqgrid is showing only in double click

Tags: jqgrid, dropdown

I created a jq-grid with one column is a drop down. When I click on the cell it gets enabled with first data of the drop down data. I need to click again to show the full array of the drop down and select the correct data. Is there anyway I can open the dropdown in the first click itself.
I am using jqgrid 5.2 paid version.

```
colModel: [                       
        { name: 'UserSelection', index: 'UserSelection', width: 180, align: "left", editable: true, edittype: "select" }
}           
loadComplete: function () {           
        jQuery("#jqgItemDetailsIssue").setColProp('UserSelection', { 
       editoptions: {
            dataUrl: 'CopyofItemInquirySubmitIssue.aspx/fillUserSelection', cacheUrlData: true,
            buildSelect: function (Result) {
                var response = $.parseJSON(Result.d);
                var s = '<select>';
                if (response && response.Table1.length) {
              for (var i = 0, l = response.Table1.length; i < l;   i++) {
              var ri = response.Table1[i];
                        s += '<option value="' + ri.Issue_ID + '" >' + ri.Issue_Type + '</option>';
                    }
```

Comment: If you use licensed version then the best is to post your question to the support of Guriddo team.